# simplexml_load_file does not show all records

Tags: php, xml

I want to show all the records in the file, for example all the codes but it only shows me the first record.

**demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductData version="2.0">
  <Product>
    <code>1000001</code>
    <name>The Name</name>
    <brand>The Brand</brand>
    <category>The Category</category>
    <specification>
      <characteristic>
        <color>The Color</color>
        <size>The Size</size>
      </characteristic>
    </specification>
    <quantity>
      <store1>0</store1>
      <store2>4</store2>
      <store3>5</store3>
      <store4>2</store4>
      <store5>3</store5>
    </quantity>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <code>1000002</code>
    <name>The Name</name>
    <brand>The Brand</brand>
    <category>The Category</category>
    <specification>
      <characteristic>
        <color>The Color</color>
        <size>The Size</size>
      </characteristic>
    </specification>
    <quantity>
      <store1>0</store1>
      <store2>4</store2>
      <store3>5</store3>
      <store4>2</store4>
      <store5>3</store5>
    </quantity>
  </Product>
</ProductData>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (file_exists('demo.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

    echo $xml->Product->code;

} else {
    exit('Error!');
}
?>
```

**Result:** 1000001

What I'm looking for: 1000001, 1000002

I hope someone can help me because this method is very practical for what I need, it would be great to be able to get all the codes, names and all the information in the same way that I get the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping will be your friend here:

```
$codes = [];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
foreach($xml->Product as $i => $product) {

    $codes[] = $product->code;

}
echo implode(', ',$codes);
```

Obviously a short example, but you can access the other items as well, and use them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
$code = $xml->xpath('*/code');

echo implode(', ', $code); // 1000001, 1000002
```

https://3v4l.org/JjRf1

Comment: It's good to know, but I think I'm left with the option to read the file because I only have to replace the file with a new one without modifying the code. Thanks crack!

Comment: I used simplexml_load_string for the sake of the example, xpath will work fine with your code.